# Cokernal of the map $B_1 \times B_2 \rightarrow [B_1,B_2]$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am reading Nakajima's book, Lectures on Hilbert Schemes of Points on Surfaces. In the proof of Theorem 1.9, it needs the following linear algebra fact.

Suppose $B_1, B_2$ are two $n \times n$ matrices in $End(k^n)$ where $k$ is a field (If you like, you could choose it to be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), we have a map 
\begin{equation}
F:End(k^n) \times End(k^n) \rightarrow End(k^n), B_1 \times B_2 \rightarrow [B_1,B_2]
\end{equation}
Then $F^{-1}(0)$ consists of commuting matrices, its differential at $B_1 \times B_2$ where $[B_1,B_2]=0$ is 
\begin{equation}
dF:\delta B_1 \times \delta B_2 \rightarrow [B_1,\delta B_2] + [\delta B_1,B_2], \delta B_1, \delta B_2 \in End(k^n)
\end{equation}
then it claims that the cokernal of this linear map is
\begin{equation}
\{ \zeta\in End(k^n)| tr(\zeta([B_1,\delta B_2] + [\delta B_1,B_2]))=0\}
\end{equation}
I do not see why!

Comment: What exactly is $dF$ as a linear map?

Comment: It is the linear map that maps two matrices $\delta B_1$ and $\delta B_2$ to $[B_1, \delta B_2]+[\delta B_1, B_2]$. Or $dF: End(k^n) \times End(k^n) \rightarrow End(k^n), C_1 \times C_2 \rightarrow [B_1,C_2]+[C_1,B_2]$ where $[B_1,B_2]=0$.